# Local passport authentication strategy gives provisional headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

From my frontend, I'm sending a POST request with a username and password object

```
const login = data => (
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/v1/user/login', data)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    })
);
```

In express, I added /login route inside /routes/v1/user.route.js

```
const controller = require('../../controllers/user.controller');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/register')
  .post(controller.register);

router.route('/login')
  .post(controller.login);

module.exports = router;
```

and the login controller method:

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/404',
    failureFlash: true });
};
```

and in my server log I see:

```
POST /v1/user/login - - ms - -
OPTIONS /v1/user/login 204 1.886 ms - 0
```

But then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passport.authenticate()` is a middleware (or rather, it's a function that returns a middleware), but you're using it as a regular function (resulting in a stalled request, because there isn't a response being sent back).

Try this:

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/404',
    failureFlash: true
});
```

Comment: this moved things a bit further so even though the authentication still has some broken parts (now I get `Error: Failed to serialize user into session` ) https://github.com/gkatsanos/isawyou/tree/master/server/src/config : I am trying to abstract the strategies in the passport.js config file and reference them in express.js (but that didn't work out so well)

Comment: btw any idea why here: https://github.com/danielfsousa/express-rest-es2017-boilerplate/blob/ea608afa04379f44821fb49bc4a16ef2d5f23d01/src/api/middlewares/auth.js#L47 the regular function works?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos notice how there, it's actually called, and gets passed `req`, `res` and `next` as arguments. That's a valid use-case. It looks like _"Failed to serialize user into session"_ is being caused by your `express.js` file not setting up `passport.serializeUser/passport.deserializeUser` (you do that in `passport.js`, but I don't that file is being used).

Comment: I see. I'm trying to find a good example - architecturally of how to split controller / passport configuration file / and express.js configuration files.. any pointers?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos there's quite an elaborate post about that here: https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html (although I haven't read it extensively myself)

Comment: one last question, am I supposed to see a cookie or something to know I have succesfully passed authentication?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos yes, `express-session` should set a session cookie.